# How do I run mulitple pythons with virtualenv in production?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have installed virtualenv to run a different version of Python than the system Python for my django app. I installed Python 2.7.11 using the method described [here](http://mbless.de/blog/2016/01/09/upgrade-to-python-2711-on-ubuntu-1404-lts.html). I've modified my uwsgi.ini file to utilize the virtualenv. When I restart nginx and uwsgi, I get the following error in my uwsgi log:

```
ImportError: /home/me/python2711/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

From the other reading I've done (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383054/python-importerror-usr-local-lib-python2-7-lib-dynload-io-so-undefined-symb) for one example), it seems the issue is related to having two different version of python conflicting with each other, which I what I thought the virtualenv was meant to resolve.

My question is, what do I need to alter in my configuration/installations to get my django app working on the Python 2.7.11 installed rather than the system install of 2.7.3?

**EDIT**

To speak to @TheBrownOne's comment below, I did install the latest version from source locally at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11` and specified that as the Python version for my virtualenv with

```
virtualenv python2711 --python=/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python
```

as part of my original roadmap. It still lead to this error.

Answer (score 4):

`virtualenv` is for managing Python package dependencies, not the version of Python itself. If you want to have specific versions of Python itself, it would probably be beneficial to look, instead, into Docker containers. Docker containers are capable of what you are describing.

**Alternatively** you can install the 2.7.11 version of Python somewhere local:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.11.tgz
cd Python-2.7.11
mkdir ~/.localpy
./configure prefix=/home/$USER/.localpy
make
make install
```

Then, modify your virtualenv to include `-p /home/$USER/.localpy/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Not really true. It is possible to have different versions of Python and pick a specific one for the virtualenv using the `-p` flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/486919.

Comment: Yes, but then you're still declaring which interpreter. You can't install two different versions of `python2.7` without the use of Docker containers, because one will overwrite the other. Alternatively, you can download the source for different versions of python and install them to custom locations and tell virtualenv to use those binaries instead. But at that point it would have been easier to use a container.

Comment: Ah, good point: I am not sure how to install different micro versions of Python 2.7 at the system level easily. Yeah, I think downloading from source can be messy. Maybe Docker containers are the way to go (although this entails a learning curve for Docker itself).

Comment: Thanks for you input. I addressed the question @TheBrownOne had regarding downloading from source in an edit to my question above. I'm trying to avoid Docker if possible. Any further suggestions?